# How to fetch username and password from text-editor-for passing values to Actionlink in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass value of loginId and Password in ActionLink for login so that can compare Id and pwd from Database.. My Code for view is mentioned below

```
Login Id:  @Html.EditorFor(Model => @Model.u_name, new { id = "tb_username", maxlength = "10", @class = "input1"})
Password:  @Html.EditorFor(Model=>Model.pwd,new { id = "tb_pwd",@class = "input1"})
@Html.ActionLink("MVC_LOginDemo", "Login", "Home", new {})
```

Comment: Don't login through query string parameters, use a form that posts. Also use PasswordFor(), not EditorFor for passwords. And can you explain with what part specifically you're having trouble?

Comment: Enclose the controls in a `form` element with `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and use a `submit` element to post the values to an action method decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Craete Action In your Controller with `Http` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(yourModelName objModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var username= objModel.u_name;
      var password=objModel.pwd;
     // get username and password from db and compare it with submitted value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass values to your action method in the controller would be to use a model, Since you already have  a model, I would suggest dont use a ActionLink instead, enclose every thing that you have there within a form and make the form submit by using a submit button Or write some jquery to detect the 
Actionlink click and submit the form. This should do the trick for you.

**Sample code (More of a Pseudo)**

```
@Html.BeginForm(id="loginForm")
{
  Login Id:  @Html.EditorFor(Model => @Model.u_name, new { id = "tb_username", maxlength = "10",    @class = "input1"})
  Password:  @Html.EditorFor(Model=>Model.pwd,new { id = "tb_pwd",@class = "input1"})
  @Html.ActionLink("MVC_LOginDemo", "Login", "Home", new {})
}
```

**JavaScript part**

```
$("MVC_LOginDemo").click(){
    $("loginForm").submit();
}
```

That should do i think. Hope this helps you.